# SELECT returns NULL instead of eliminating rows that do not apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

The following query generates one line of Xml code for each row in my table that meets the conditions:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
        [memberid],
        [purchaseid],
        CONVERT(DATE, [time]) AS [time],
        [depID],
        [theme],
        [parentgroup],  
        (SELECT 
             [transactionid],
             [quantity],
             [price],
             [articlenumber],
             [articlename],
             [articlesubgroupname],
             [brand],
             [articlecategory],
             [maincategory]
         FOR XML PATH('transaction'), TYPE) AS transactions
    WHERE 
        quantity > 0 AND 
        memberid IS NOT NULL AND 
        DATALENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(memberid))) > 0
    FOR XML PATH('receipt')) AS rowXml
FROM 
    TransactionsDSEDelta AS t
```

When I run the query, instead of eliminating the rows in which the condition `quantity > 0` does not apply, I am getting a `NULL`. This means if there are 10 records in the table `TransactionsDSEDelta` where only 5 of them have a positive `quantity`, all 10 records are returned but 5 of them are `NULL`.

I wonder why my query is generating those records?

Comment: will you be able to share a repro for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` should be in the *outer* query:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT
        [memberid],
        [purchaseid],
        CONVERT(DATE,[time]) AS [time],
        [depID],
        [theme],
        [parentgroup],  
        (
            SELECT 
                [transactionid],
                [quantity],
                [price],
                [articlenumber],
                [articlename],
                [articlesubgroupname],
                [brand],
                [articlecategory],
                [maincategory]
            FOR XML PATH('transaction'), TYPE
        ) AS transactions
    FOR XML PATH('receipt')
) AS rowXml
FROM TransactionsDSEDelta AS t
WHERE quantity > 0 AND 
      memberid IS NOT NULL AND 
      DATALENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(memberid))) > 0;
```

You cannot filter rows in the `SELECT` statement.  You need to filter rows in the `WHERE`.  Your original query is basically:

```
select . . .,
       (select . . .
        FOR XML PATH('receipt')
       )
from TransactionsDSEDelta AS t;
```

This selects everything in the `TransactionsDSEDelta`.  If something is filtered out in the subquery, it gets a `NULL` value (as you have observed).

Comment: correct. thank you. will accept as answer when StackOverflow allows me to.